# Vuex state keeps saying its undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Here is my `post.js` under `src > store > post.js`:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        testState: 'Hello',
        TV: 0,
    },

    getters: {
    
    },

    mutations: {

    },

    actions: {

    }
})
```

My `index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import post from './post'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
    post
  }
})
```

And finally I tried accessing the state in a component.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h3>{{ testState }} {{ TV }}</h3>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import store from './store'
import { mapActions, mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data(){
    return {
  
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['testState'])
  }
}
</script>
```

However, it keeps giving me an error on the console that says:

```
Property or method "testState" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

When I check in the Vue panel (Chrome's devtools) and I check under Vuex, I can clearly see the `testState: 'hello'` there so the state exists.

Any tips/advices? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. You can use [namespaced modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing)

```
// post.js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        testState: 'Hello',
        TV: 0,
    },
    getters: {
     getTestState: state => state.testState
    },
    mutations: {
      setTestState(state, payload) {
          state.testState = payload
      }
    },
    actions: {
      setTestState({ commit }, payload) {
         commit('setTestState', payload)
      }
    }

}
```

```
// index.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import post from './post'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
    post
  }
})
```

```
// Component

computed: {
    ...mapState('post', ['testState', 'TV']),
    ...mapGetters('post', 'getTestState') // this.getTestState
},
methods: {
   ...mapActions('post', ['setTestState']) // this.setTestState('hello from action')
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error `[vuex] module namespace not found in mapState(): post/`

Comment: Did you added this `namespaced: true` in post.js

Comment: Yes I did. I even tried copying the code here to mine.

Comment: There's a type mistake `)` in `post.js`, have to seen this?,  Removed check once

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a module try out:

```
...mapState({testState:state=>state.post.testState})
```

Your module shouldn't create a store instance, it should be like :

```
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        testState: 'Hello',
        TV: 0,
    },

    getters: {
    
    },

    mutations: {

    },

    actions: {

    }
}
```

Comment: you could also do `...mapState('post',{testState:state=>state.testState})`

Comment: It gives me this error `[vuex] module namespace not found in mapState(): post/`

Comment: you should add `namespaced: true` in your module

Comment: And also, what if I want to use a getter or an action?

Comment: Yes Sir I tried that as well too, like the other answer given.